# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component even with axios cancel token in place

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using an Axios cancel request which I thought was to prevent this error yet I am still getting it. Basically I enter a screen where it is fetching data from the server. If I go back to the previous screen before it has finished loading I get the error.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    setLoading(true);
    const getPub = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.get("https://.....", {
          cancelToken: ourRequest.token,
        });
        if (response.data) {
          const info = await Axios.get(
            'http://anotherurl', {
                cancelToken: ourRequest.token,
             });
          setPub(pubInfo.data);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getPub();
    return () => {
      ourRequest.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request was successfully canceled and it will go to catch block, however the catch block performed a setState "setLoading(false)" but the component was already unmounted. You may performed a condition on catch block to check if the request was canceled.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (err) {
    if(!request is canceled){
        setError(err);
        setLoading(false);
    }
}
```